# Generate Odoo11 Custom Reports with Wizard. Format error: Not a PDF or corrupted

Tags: report, odoo, wizard, odoo-11

i'm trying to print an Odoo custom report based on a wizard.
it takes inputs from a wizard view. The wizard lets the user select a project with start_date and end_date. and click print button. so the list of activities that match the wizard form fields filter should be printed in a `PDF`. but i got a `PDF` file with `0 KB` and when i try to open i get `Format error: Not a PDF or corrupted.` and there is no errors in console
Here is some key files

**reports/__init__.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from odoo import models, api
class ReportWorkPlan(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'ewonga_pta.report_model_work_plan'

    @api.model
    def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
        docs = self.env['ew.pta.line'].browse(docids)


        docargs = {
            "doc_ids": docs.ids,
            "doc_model": "ew.pta.line",
            "docs": docs,

        }
        return docargs
```

**reports/print_work_plan_template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<odoo>

    <template id="report_work_plan_template">
   <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <h2>Report title</h2>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

</odoo>
```

**reports/work_plan_report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<odoo>
    <report
        id="action_work_plan_print_report"
        string="Print Report"
        model="ewonga_pta.report_model_work_plan"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="ewonga_pta.report_work_plan_template"
        file="print_work_plan_template"
    />


</odoo>
```

**wizards/workplan.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api


class WorkPlanWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "ewonga_pta.work_plan_wizard"

#     attendee_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', string="Attendees")
    project_id = fields.Many2one("account.analytic.account", domain=[("type_interne", "=", "projet" )])
    start_date = fields.Date("Date de début")
    end_date = fields.Date("Date de fin")

    @api.multi
    def check_report(self):
        data = {}
        data["form"] = self.read(
            [
                "project_id",
                "start_date",
                "end_date"   
            ]
        )[0]
        return self.env.ref("ewonga_pta.action_work_plan_print_report").report_action(self, data=data)
```

**wizards/wizard_work_plan.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

        <record id="action_work_plan_wizard_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Generate Workplan Report</field>
    <field name="res_model">ewonga_pta.work_plan_wizard</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="work_plan_wizard_form_view"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>


    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="work_plan_wizard_form_view">
            <field name="name">work_plan_wizard.form</field>
            <field name="model">ewonga_pta.work_plan_wizard</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Add Attendees">
                    <group col="4" colspan="4">
                        <field name="project_id"/>
                        <field name="start_date"/>
                        <field name="end_date"/>
                    </group>

                    <group col="4" colspan="4">
                        <footer>
                  <button name="check_report" string="Imprimer" type="object" default_focus="1" class="oe_highlight"/>
                  or
                  <button string="Annuler" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
              </footer>
                    </group>
                </form>



            </field>
        </record>



</odoo>
```

os: Window 10 x64

python: version 3.6.5

wkhtmltopdf: version 0.12.3.2 (with patched qt)

please help me to solve this issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your "data" parameters pass thru "report_action" call. Self already contain datas.

Thanks